# graph lookup in postgres typeorm, get data in a chain model

Tags: json, postgresql, typeorm

I need to get data in a chain model in typeorm postgres.

tables

```
userTable
========
id(uuid)
name:string
parentId:string
```

Data in userTable

================

```json
{
id:"56465d4fsdf6s54df65s4d6f5",
name:"amal",
parent_id:"65s465fs4d6f54sd5f46sd4f"
},
{
id:"654654156415645sc45ssgsdg",
name:"jith",
parent_id:"56465d4fsdf6s54df65s4d6f5"
},
{
id:"56465d4fsdf6s54df65s4d6f5",
name:"navya",
parent_id:"654654156415645sc45ssgsdg"
},
{
id:"sf6sdf5ds646d4v6d6f45d64",
name:"brito"
parent_id:"56465d4fsdf6s54df65s4d6f5"
}
```

**i need to fetch data like**

```json
[{
id:"56465d4fsdf6s54df65s4d6f5",
name:"amal",
parent_id:"65s465fs4d6f54sd5f46sd4f",
child[
{ id:"654654156415645sc45ssgsdg", name:"jith", parent_id:"56465d4fsdf6s54df65s4d6f5", 
child[
{id:"56465d4fsdf6s54df65s4d6f5",
name:"navya", 
parent_id:"654654156415645sc45ssgsdg",
child:[]
}
]
}
]
},{
id:"sf6sdf5ds646d4v6d6f45d64",
name:"brito",
parent_id:"56465d4fsdf6s54df65s4d6f5",
child:[]
}]
```

Comment: So you need a SQL query that converts a result into JSON?

Comment: yes, in type orm

Comment: have any idea bro